# Example of an Algebraic Space ("false" affine line with different tangents at origin)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, algebraic-spaces

I have a question about the following example from the [Algebraic spaces and quotients by equivalence relation of schemes](https://people.kth.se/%7Eskjelnes/Pdffiler/algspaces.pdf) by Roy Mikael Skjelnes (page 12)
of a presheaf quotient, which
has associated sheaf which can not be a scheme.
It's originally an example from Knutson's book on Algebraic spaces, but there my concern also isn't
answered. Here the example:

> **Example 2.15.** . The following example is based on (*[Knu71], page 9*).
> Let $X = Spec(k[x, y]/(xy))$ again be the coordinate cross. Let $R$ be the
> disjoint union of $X$ and $X_0$, where $X_0 = X \ (0, 0)$ is the complement
> of the origin. We consider the two morphisms $\pi_i: R \to X$, where $\pi_1$
> is the natural inclusion on both components of $R$. The morphism $\pi_2$ is
> the identity on the component $X$, but on the other component $X_0$ the
> morphism $\pi_2$ switches the axes. Note that the two maps $\pi_1$ and
> $\pi_1$ are Zariski local open immersions.

> The glueing of $X$ along $R$ will give the affine line, but the quotient
> sheaf $A$, of $R \rightrightarrows X$ is not a scheme, in any topology.
> To see this note that the presheaf quotient has, over the origo, different
> tangent directions sticking out. Since the presheaf quotient is separated
> (Proposition (1.13)), these tangent directions will also appear in the
> sheaf quotient. Hence, since the sheaf quotient is different from the affine line, it follows that the sheaf quotient can not be a scheme.

> Thus, the non-scheme like points, as the tangent directions in the
> above example, are not particular for algebraic spaces being etale quotient
> sheaves by ´etale equivalence relations. One encounters these nonscheme
> points when taking Zariski quotient sheaves by Zariski equivalence
> relations.

By consruction of the quotient of $R \rightrightarrows X$
the resulting presheaf quotient has, over the origin, two
different tangent directions sticking out.

Then it is clamed that since
the presheaf quotient is separated (Proposition
(1.13)), these tangent directions will also appear
in the sheaf quotient. I do not understand. The Proposition
(1.13) states:

> Proposition 1.13. Let $\operatorname{Cov}$ be a pretopology, and let $R$ and
> $X$ be two sheaves. Assume that we have an equivalence relation
> $R \rightrightarrows X$, and
> let $X_R$ denote its presheaf quotient. Then the presheaf $X_R$
> is separated.
> In particular we have that $LX_R$ is a sheaf, and that the equivalence
> relation is effective, i.e. $R = X \times{LX_R} X$.
> (Here: $LF$ is defined by
> $LF(S)\mathrel{:=} \lim_{T \to S \in \operatorname{Cov}(S)} F(T)$; see also page 5.)

Question: Proposition (1.13) states only that the presheaf
(of the quotient) is separated, there is no statement about the separateness of the sheaf itself. So I not see why all tangent directions, which apear in the presheaf, must also apear without any loss in hypothetically existing associated sheaf?

Secondly: I know that separatedness means that it 'separates' points
(= $\operatorname{Spec}(k) \to X$-morphisms)
in algebro-geometric setting. Does it also 'separate'
tangent directions?

Comment: Questions should not rely on images.  Please type out the relevant portion of the text about which you want to ask questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing two completely different notions of "separated".

A presheaf of sets $F$ on a site is called "separated" if whenever $\{U_i \to U\}$ is a covering family, $F(U) \to \prod F(U_i)$ is injective. This is the notion that Skjelnes is talking about. The sheafification of a presheaf of sets is often constructed by iterating twice an endofunctor $L$ on presheaves such that $L$ takes arbitrary presheaves to separated presheaves and separated presheaves to sheaves.

There is also the algebro-geometric notion of separated, which corresponds (for schemes over the complex numbers) to being Hausdorff. This is completely unrelated. In particular the line with doubled tangents along the origin is *not* separated in the algebro-geometric sense. But it is of course separated as a presheaf of sets, since it is an algebraic space, and in particular a sheaf of sets.

Comment: oh yes sorry, you are right, that's page 5, I overlooked it. But I still 
not understand how this fact that the presheaf quotient is separated
in the sense above, implies that the tangent directions 
must also appear in sheaf quotient (if it would exist).

Comment: What Skjelnes is using is that if $F$ is a separated presheaf of sets, then $F(U)\to LF(U)$ is injective. So separated presheaves have the property that sections map injectively into the sheafification.

Comment: ...and then we take for $U$ the dual numbers $D=Spec(k[\epsilon])$, since $F(D)$ represent with the tangent vectors of this presheaf, that finishes the argument, right?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely my reading.